# Java selenium error in unix box

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, jvm, xvfb

I am trying to run selenium script in unix box . I have installed firefox version 24.7.0 and xvfb . While running the code , I am getting below error .
    Cant figure out the error , please help.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGBUS (0x7) at pc=0x00002b5d957e697b, pid=2570, tid=47680957966656

    #
    # JRE version: 6.0_22-b04
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (17.1-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
    # Problematic frame:
    # C  [libc.so.6+0x7a97b]  memset+0xa5b
    #
    # An error report file with more information is saved as:
    # /tmp/tmp/hs_err_pid2570.log
```

Comment: Could it be that your /tmp directory is full ?

Comment: I got the above error 3-4 times . Now I am able to run it but getting below error

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 8080;

Comment: 8080 seems a very strange port with which to connect to a browser via WebDriver. I'd expect a Tomcat to be running there. Can you please check that value?